# Ionic Capacitor still referring to cordova-support-google-services on Android builds, when removed

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I recently updated my Ionic 5 app to Capacitor. Originally i have using notification messages with Firebase using the cordova libary `'@ionic-native/push/ngx`.

I also had **`cordova-support-google-services`** installed, therefore i also removed it thinking Capacitor already includes notification plugin.

Now when i try to preform a RUN using "ionic capacitor run", Android Studio starts, i get the follow output

```
org.gradle.api.resources.MissingResourceException: Could not read script 'G:\AVR_Project\Ionic Projects\app\node_modules\cordova-support-google-services\build.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

It seems like it is still trying to use the cordova version, that i removed and not the default capacitor version.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

after you uninstall the plugin, run `npx cap sync android`, that should remove the gradle reference from the plugin

Comment: Thanks, That error has gone, but i have not got a a large set of more errors still related to notification messages,
 e.g. cannot find symbol class NotificationCompat

It seems there is a notification folder still in "capacitor-cordova-android-plugins", which is causing all these issues.

 Is there away to check if a cordova plugins is causing this?

Comment: Run `npm install jetifier`, `npx jetify` and `npx cap sync android` again

Comment: Thanks got it working, got some new issues but will posts a new question